# Do 2 month old kittens need freshly softened food?

Tags: cats, diet

These kittens' mom dissapeared (inside-outside cat on a farm) a month ago. I've sort of lost track of how old they are, but probably no more that 2 months now.

[image]

I've been feeding them solid food ever since; we have a big bag of adult cat food and I've been moderately soaking it in water, then microwaving for a little while to get the water soaked into it. They've been eating, but its hard to tell if they're eating much after it dries. Do I need to keep freshly softened food out, or can they eat it just fine dry at 2 months?

Answer (score 3):

2 months is completely fine to feed them dry food.

Make sure the food you give is labeled for kittens as they need a larger portion of vit/min/fats/protein than they would as an adult or senior.

Comment: I agree they can eat dry food at that age, but make sure they actually eat it. I got my kitten at seven weeks and she would not eat dry food at all. I had to softened it with cat milk and also fed some wet food on top of dry food. It took a few months before she was switched over to eating pure dry food.